# change border width on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, border

I have a list of links, and I want the visual effect of the border at the bottom or the top of the link to change its width on hover. I tried to do that, but the width of border change and the text move up and down.

I want the text be fixed and border width change behind the text!

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="first">first</div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="second">second</div></a>
    </li>
</ul> 

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    height:30px;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height:30px;
}
div {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
div.first {
    border-bottom-color: #aaa;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    transition: border 1s ease;
}
div.second {
   border-top-color: #aaa;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    transition: border 1s ease;
}
div:hover {
    border-width:30px;
}
```

Demo:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acy33ce4/)

Comment: `i want the text be fixed and border width change behind the text` maybe you want to change background color?

Comment: no i want it with animation (slide down), it maybe done with jQuery animate but i want it in css if it possible !

Comment: or slide up .. according to border position

Comment: Can't be done with borders as they will change the height of the object (especially with content inside them). I'd use a pseudo-element.

Comment: see this jsfiddle.net/ym7tynws/1 @Paulie_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i fixed it by adding height to the div instead of border, and increase the height on hover and here is the example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym7tynws/3/)

```
a div {
    background-color:#333;
    height:2px;
    line-height:30px;
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
}
a div:hover {
    height:30px;
}
```

Thank you all for help

Comment: yes but after two days, I should wait to tomorrow :) @AdrienBe

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiidle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ym7tynws/2/

All you have to do now is work on `z-index` of the second tab.

CSS:

```
    .nav {
    list-style:none;
    width:200px;
}
.nav li {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.nav li a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a .menu-link {
    background-color:#eee;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-color:#333;
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}
a div:hover {
    border-bottom-width:30px;
}

.second {

    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#eee;
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.second:before{
    background: #333;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
}

.second:before {
    top: 0;
}

.second:hover:before {
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
    height:30px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>
     <a><div class="menu-link">About</div></a>
</li>
<li>
     <a><div class="second">Contact Us</div></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible because the border itself occupies space in the document, it is part of the box model so it's height  is taken into consideration. If you want changes in height to not affect the rest of the document you must remove the element from the normal document flow.

I'd suggest that you create a fake border using height on a pseudo-element and absolutely position it against the parent element, like this:

```
.first,
.second {
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
position: relative;
}

.first:after,
.second:before{
background: #aaa;
height: 2px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
content: "";
display: inline-block;
left: 0;
}

.first:after {
    top: 100%;
}

.second:before {
    top: 0;
}

.first:hover:after,
.second:hover:before {
    height:30px;
}
```

Here's an update of your Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jkaL3a6m/

The other option would be to use the box-shadow property instead of border to create a fake 'border'.

Comment: but i really used it and worked fine with bottom border ! here is the example i wrote it , but when i change it to top does not work http://jsfiddle.net/ym7tynws/1/

Comment: @user3003810 What? Does my fiddle not answer your question?

Comment: actually no, even I add z-index, I solved it using height http://jsfiddle.net/ym7tynws/3/